# How to read or import shapefile into android studio in order to view the ArcGIS

Tags: android, arcgis-android

I am developing an ArcGIS project with Android Studio IDE, to view some maps and information and I would like to read some shapefiles from another project. But I couldn't find a solution on how to do it yet. Anyone know how to do it?

I would like to add/read/import shapefiles into my ArcGIS map as a layer.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Esri's Android SDK, but it seems that you can load a shapefile using the ShapefileFeatureTable class: https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/core/geodatabase/ShapefileFeatureTable.html

Comment: thanks PolyGeo ... i will try it with ur suggestion... and let you know how it is turned out.. :)

Answer (score 1):

ShapefileFeatureTable allows a shapefile to be opened and displayed in a map using a FeatureLayer. Basic usage offered below:

```
ShapefileFeatureTable mTable;
    try {
  mTable = new ShapefileFeatureTable(mShapefilePath);
  mFlayer = new FeatureLayer(mTable);
  mMapView.addLayer(mFlayer);
  Log.d("**ShapefileTest**", "SpatialReference : "+ mTable.getSpatialReference());
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  Log.d("**ShapefileTest**", "File not found in SDCard, nothing to load");
}
```

Comment: thanks jdONeill.... it's worked :)

mMapView.addLayer(featureLayer);

        try {
            shapefileTable = new ShapefileFeatureTable(filepath+"/DS_EserviceLine.shp");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            android.util.Log.v( "DebugLabel", "Program Error"+e );
        }

        featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(shapefileTable);